# Select just values with dash on end of strig

Tags: sql, select

I have values like this:

```
link_rewrite
value1
-value2
value3-
value4-
value5
-value6
value7-
value8
value9
value10
```

```
SELECT link_rewrite FROM product WHERE link_rewrite RIGHT('%-%', 1);
```

I want to get just values ending or starting with -

```
link_rewrite
-value2
value3-
value4-
-value6
value7-
```

Comment: where LEFT(link_rewrite, 1) = '-' OR RIGHT(link_rewrite, 1) = '-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT link_rewrite FROM product WHERE link_rewrite LIKE '-%' or link_rewrite LIKE '%-' ;
```

does this work for you?

**%** is the wild card which will pick up the rows based on your requirement in this case anything with "-" in the beginning in the first case (before OR) and end in the last case (AFTER OR)

Comment: Perfect!!

Would I be able to remove the - from all records with a simple update?

Comment: yes you can remove using the update command I believe. If the above answer is working for you can you then please consider upvoting for me https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for upvoting